# How to repair my corrupted local git repo branch and rebase my Github fork?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am new to git and am still trying to get an overall handle on how forks, origins, upstreams, and branches work.

I created a fork in Github, created a local copy of the fork, identified my upstream and origin branches, and created a 'newbranch'. I did my development on my local 'newbranch', pushed it to my fork on Github, and created a pull request back to the upstream repo. Then I made some changes in my fork directly, on Github. Later, I made changes to my local copy without updating from Github. I've resolved this by merging from 'newbranch' in the Github fork.

So far, so good. However, I have now been attempting to update my branch from the upstream repo and have run into trouble.

After committing changes to my 'newbranch' and pushing them to the fork, I did the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

This resulted in thousands of conflicts. I did a reset to back out the merge but was still left with thousands of modified files in the branch and I can't figure out how to clean them up.

I created 'newbranch' from the 'devel' branch of the upstream repo. If you're wondering why I was messing with the 'master' branch, that makes two of us.

My Github fork says my 'devel' branch is 40,000 commits behind the upstream repo. I would like to clean up my local repo, update my local 'devel' and 'newbranch' branches from the upstream repo, and sync these changes to my Github fork.

Any help in getting out of this mess is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what I did was follow the Github instructions too literally without a clear enough understanding. Probably because there was quite a while between the creation of 'newbranch' and this problem of rebasing.

'newbranch' was created from devel, not master. So when I attempted to merge 'upstream/master' with 'newbranch', there were thousands of conflicts. I could probably have repaired my repo with a simple `git reset --hard` command but this is what I did, instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/MYACCOUNT/REPO.git
git remote add upstream https://github.com/UPSTREAM/REPO.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout devel
git pull upstream devel
git push
git checkout vhosts-package
git rebase devel
git push
```

My changes had already been committed so there was nothing else to do. Like I said, a hard reset might have cleared it up but this worked and I'm happy.

Hope this is some help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come out of this mess there are a couple of simple ways

1) Create a new-branch from upstream and delete the previous branch and rename the current branch and then force push to your fork.

2) `git reset --hard HEAD~<some x number of commits>`, then fast forward the current branch by `git pull`, then `cherry-pick` commits you want from the history by visiting reflog

Comment: Is this really the only way? The forked repository has not been corrupted and I have submitted a pull request to the upstream repo. It appears that the 'master' branch in my local repo is corrupted, though. I would be perfectly happy to dump my local repo and reload it from Github since that should include my 'newbranch'. Will that work? What would be the steps to then update my local repo from upstream and push those updates to the Github fork?

Comment: it may not be the only way but I feel it is simple when you are completely messed.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think I had trouble understanding your solution but I think it would have been easier if I had. Ended up rebuilding my local repo. All good now.